# Modify bash autocomplete rule to exclude particular file names

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I want to modify the existing `vi` bash autocompletion rule to exclude some filenames (for example, the `config.log` file).  I tried using the `FIGNORE` environmental variable, but that didn't work.  Using the `complete` builtin overrides the existing rule, rather than modifying it.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Overwriting data in `/usr/share/` doesn't sound clever to me. Instead a modified definition of `_install_xspec ()` should be put in `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the current configuration with

```
complete -p vi
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o filenames -o nospace -F _exp_ vi
```

and the definition of the used shell function with

```
type _exp_
```

There is a `complete` feature / option `-X` which allows to filter the results. The problem is that this applies only to to `complete` actions. It does not apply to the `-o default` results (I don't know about `-o bashdefault`).

You can change the compspec:

```
complete -d -f -o filenames -o nospace -F _exp_ -X '@(config.log|config.doc)' vi
```

Unfortulately

1. you can have only one `-X` in the `complete` call (former ones are overwritten)
2. you need `shopt -s extglob` for the above to work; otherwise you are limited to a single name or pattern (`"*.log"`)

Comment: That worked, thanks.  I wish there was a better way to do it.

Comment: @MatthewCline Try my solution below. It worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

To exclude uninteresting filenames or extensions from bash completion, add this line to your .bashrc file:

```
FIGNORE=".log:.dvi:.pdf:"
```